# GWT Editors: How to record changes to fields and sub-editors? (RequestFactory?)

Tags: gwt, requestfactory, gwtp, gwt-editors

I have an app that makes extensive use of the Editor Framework. Right now I'm at the point where I want to add a new feature: if a user edits an entity, I'd like to record which changes were made and store them in a separate datastore entity. This requires knowing if a field was changed, the field name, and the value it was changed to.

This is what I'd like to implement:

1. App calls edit(bean);
2. User makes changes, calls flush() and data gets sent back to server.
3. In server handler, changes from the bean are sent to `processChanges(List<String> paths)` which then creates and stores the record that "field foo" was changed to "bar", and so on.
4. The entity is saved, overwriting the existing one.

I use GWTP and currently use the RPC Command Pattern. I've read a bit about RequestFactory and as I understand, one of its main benefits is that it only sends the changed fields known as "deltas" back to the server to minimise the payload, so I'm wondering if using RequestFactory would be a better fit for my app?

Apologies - I've been reading through the GWT docs and Javadocs for the Editor Framework and RequestFactory but I'm still pretty confused. [RequestFactoryEditorDriver.getPaths()](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/web/bindery/requestfactory/gwt/client/RequestFactoryEditorDriver.html#getPaths()) seems like it might be what I need but any advice or pointers greatly appreciated.

I could probably watch for changes client-side but that seems like a bad idea.

Comment: I don't see 100% how this is related to GWT Editors specifically or GWT at all.
Sounds more like a restructuring of the Database/Datastore problem, e.g. saving the history of an entity.

Comment: I think you misunderstand my problem. How is restructuring my schema going to help me find out which fields have had their content changed when I call `EditorDriver.flush()`? I am re-saving the same entity, not creating a new copy each time, hence the need to record changes separately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you could do that using an [`EditorVisitor`](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/editor/client/EditorVisitor.html), similar to the `DirtCollector` visitor used internally by the Editor framework (have a look at the `PathCollector` for how to collect paths in a visitor).

I would start by visiting the hierarchy to collect the initial values just after the call to `edit()` (this is done already by the `DirtCollector` internally, but there's no way to access its results, and it only collects *leaf values* anyway).
Then you could call `flush()` ans see whether there are errors, and possibly validated your object to see if everything's OK. Then you visit the hierarchy again to collect the changes (against the initial values you previously collected) so you can send them to the server.

Comment: Thanks Thomas. It seems like this is a simple task so I'm going to leave it for now. I'll be refactoring all of my databinding code at some point soon so maybe I'll go for requestfactory then as it seems really useful.

Comment: My answer is not at all linked to RequestFactory, it's **only** using the Editor framework.

Comment: I understand that, but would it not be easier to track the names of fields and which ones have been edited using `RequestFactory` proxies rather than using an `EditorVisitor` to traverse the tree myself?

Comment: My initial comment should have read "this is NOT a simple task" - Doh!

Comment: It depends on your constraints. RequestFactory has a steep learning curve and quite a bit of constraints; it clearly doesn't fit every use-case. I think the visitor approach might be cheaper than moving to RequestFactory.